# Como hacer que 3 elementos se conviertan/comporten como un solo elemento en HTML + CSS?

Tags: html, css, xml, table, style

tengo una imagen y dos párrafos (p) que quiero que se comporten como un solo elemento para que cuando llegue al límite establecido salte a una nueva hoja de impresión en PDF

Este sería mi código:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="signature.gif">
                <p>BY:_____________________</p>
                <p>AUTHORIZED SIGNATURE</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

El cual es la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando dices que quieres que se comporten como un solo elemento, te refieres a que el contenido (la imagen y los dos párrafos) no queden en dos páginas diferentes, sino que siempre queden juntos?

Comment: Si, exactamente eso, que quede todo junto y si tiene que dar un salto de página (Cuando llega al limite inferior) que salte todo el contenido y no solo una parte

Comment: ¿Cómo se genera el PDF? ¿Cómo podríamos reproducir el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad CSS [break-inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside)

Según MDN, traducción libre:

> La propiedad `break-inside` establece cómo deben comportarse los
> saltos de página, columnas o región dentro de un contenedor (caja)
> generado. Si no se genera ningún contenedor, la propiedad se ignora.

Esta propiedad reemplaza a `page-break-inside`, que aunque aún funciona, se recomienda no usar.

Supongo que sólo te interesa que no se "rompa" al momento de imprimir en PDF, por lo tanto estoy usando la [regla `@media print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@media#media_types)

Si quieres ver un ejemplo real, también te comparto el [enlace a CodePen,](https://codepen.io/JheyMejia/pen/rNdMEvb) prueba imprimiendo desde ahí.

```css
@media print {
  table,
  tr,
  td {
    break-inside: avoid;
  }
}


/* Solo para ejemplo */

.texto {
  background: yellow;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="texto">texto</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100">
        <p>BY:_____________________</p>
        <p>AUTHORIZED SIGNATURE</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Con la propiedad break-inside:
[image: Imagen de ejemplo con la regla print]

Sin la propiedad y con el salto de línea.
[image: Imagen de ejemplo sin la regla print]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tan valiosa ayuda, pero sigue sin funcionar, sigue rompiendo y no toma a los elementos como si fuera un solo elemento.

Comment: Edita por favor tu pregunta, añadiendo un código mas completo en el que se pueda reproducir tu problema. La estructura de la tabla es la misma? Revisa el orden de la declaración CSS, que se aplique a lo que tienes